# Json4s 'linq-style' for-comprehension giving empty list

Tags: scala, json4s

Trying to run the following test from the example in the Readme https://github.com/json4s/json4s#linq-style 
but I get an empty list. I don't the result List(5, 3) specified in the example

```
  test("JValue with for comprehension") {
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

    val json = parse( """
     { "name": "joe",
       "children": [
         {
           "name": "Mary",
           "age": 5
         },
         {
           "name": "Mazy",
           "age": 3
         }
       ]
     }
                  """)

    val result = for {JField("age", JInt(age)) <- json} yield age
    println(result)

    //Output : List()
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

OK found the problem. We first need to add a generator clause to to create a JObject from the json

```
val result = for { JObject(child) <- json
                   JField("age", JInt(age))  <- child} 
             yield age
//Output : List(5, 3)
```